# Spring Boot/Auth0 error: No Connections enabled for the client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, auth0

I am working on setting up Auth0 with my Spring Boot application. I've been following Auth0's guide (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/01-login), but am getting an error:

```
Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_request] no connections enabled for the client
https://[removed].auth0.com/
```

The Allowed Callback URL is set to: http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/auth0

The spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client has been added

I have the following in my application.properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-id=[removed]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-secret=[removed]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[0]=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.issuer-uri=https\://[removed].auth0.com/
```

The SecurityFilterChain and Controller are both direct copies from the guide. The index.html page has a link to:

```
<a th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/auth0}">Log In</a>
```

I can't find anything on Auth0's website or any forum that to help determine where the error is coming from. Any ideas on where I can look?

Comment: Did you activate the auth0 api for scope email with that authentication flow ? Check your params twice, and start your spring app in debug mode to get more valuable stacktrace please.

Comment: I am confirming with our admin that the scope is correct. I re-copied the params. Error displays on the page itself, not on the application. No stacktrace.

Comment: @BendaThierry.com, another member of our team provided the legacy code they use to manually generate the Auth0 URL. The Spring Boot URL is missing the "connection" parameter that allows it to work. I asked it as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159954/spring-boot-auth0-how-do-i-add-connection-as-a-url-parameter