# Spring Boot/Auth0 - How do I specify the connection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, auth0

I am working on setting up an application using Spring Boot and Auth0. We are refactoring from a legacy codebase to use Spring Boot. In the legacy code, the Auth0 URL is created manually by appending the URL parameters:

```
https://[removed].auth0.com/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &client_id=[removed]
    &scope=openid email profile
    &connection=[removed]
    &state=[removed]
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/auth0
```

With the Spring Boot configuration (guide here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/01-login), this is the URL that generates:

```
https://[removed].auth0.com/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &client_id=[removed]
    &scope=openid email profile
    &state=[removed]
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/auth0
```

The Spring Boot URL is giving me an error "[invalid_request] no connections enabled for the client".

I am missing the "connection" parameter with the Spring Boot setup. I have tested by manually copying the URL and adding the "connection" parameter and I get the login page. Without it, I get the error.

On Spring's configuration page (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings), I don't see an option for Connection. I didn't see anything on the SecurityFilterChain that would allow me to change this either.

I see that Auth0.js has a function that allows a "connection" parameter (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js). How do I add this using Spring Boot/Java?

**EDIT**

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-id=[removed]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-secret=[removed]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[0]=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[1]=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[2]=profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.issuer-uri=[removed]
```

**EDIT 2**

We were working in conjunction with Auth0 Support - they provided us the following information:

> In case an Enterprise connection is the only enabled connection for an
> application and the "connection" parameter is not specified on the
> /authorize request, you need to enable the "show as a button" setting
> on that enterprise connection, otherwise you will get "no connections
> enabled for the client" error.
>
> The "Display connection as a button" checkbox is on the "Login
> Experience" tab of the connection setting page.

Weird configuration requirement - you can't go directly to the login page. You have to have a button to take you there. This did resolve the original issue; however, I marked @Codo answer below as accepted, as it did answer this question and appears it would work from initial testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a way to add an additional parameter to the authorization URI. It's isn't as straightforward as one would like but doable.

Fortunately, it's described in [Customizing Authorization and Token Requests with Spring Security 5.1 Client](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests).

You probably want to implement the steps 2 and 4:

- Add your own implementation of `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`, override both `resolve()` methods to call `customizeAuthorizationRequest()`
- Implement `customizeAuthorizationRequest()` to add the additional `connection` parameter (`OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` already support additional parameters)
- Implement a security configuration class to register `CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver` as the authorization request resolver

Several issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security) ask for a simpler way. But the issues are still open (or closed as duplicates).

**Update**

Instead of `clientRegistrationRepository()` (at the end of step 2), you could declare `clientRegistrationRepository` as an injected dependency and the use it without parentheses:

```
@Autowired
private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
```

Comment: That looks like it may work. I'm working on setting it up, but at the end of Step 2, it has: http.oauth2Login()
          .authorizationEndpoint()
          .authorizationRequestResolver(
            new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
              clientRegistrationRepository(), "/oauth2/authorize-client")). The method "clientRegistrationRepository()" isn't defined anywhere. I don't want to override the default ClientRegistration, just add to it. How do I pass the default?

Comment: I've overlooked that one. You might be able to inject it (see my update). I haven't tried it though. It's unfortunately typical for Spring: If you provide your own implementation of a class, it can quickly get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security comes with with mostly preconfigured Auth0 module. Unless you're doing something specific, there's no need to construct URL yourself.
Have you done Spring configuration as said in the link you've posted: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/01-login#configure-spring-security ?

```
# src/main/resources/application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          auth0:
            ...
```

Comment: I understand I don't need to construct the URL myself. The second URL listed above is the one Spring generates. I added the applicaiton.properties configuration to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (untested):

In `application.properties`, specify all URLs separately. So instead of:

```ini
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.issuer-uri=xyz.us.auth0.com
```

Specify:

```ini
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.authorization-uri=https://xyz.us.auth0.com/authorize?connection=azuread
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.token-uri=https://xyz.us.auth0.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.jwk-set-uri=https://xyz.us.auth0.com/=.well-known/jwks.json
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.user-info-uri=https://xyz.us.auth0.com/userinfo
```

Note that the authorization URI already includes the *connection* parameters. All the other parameters should then be appended.

You can get all the URIs at https://xyz.us.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration (just replace "xyz" and put the URL in your browser).